# Misplaced Layout after "home"-button and/or powersave screen

Tags: android, layout

I have an app which also includes a service with a Notification.
Right now I am experiencing the foillowing problem :

- I start my app which will work fine
- after couple of minutes the powersave kicks in and I get a black screen
- I (or hte user) click the Menu-button to dismiss the black screen and to unlock the screenlock
- Now my (fullscreen) app will have "moved" like 30-40 pixels downwards, creating an ugly black border or hole. When I move the scrollwheel it will move up and down, and when I press the Menu button (showing my ap''s menu) it will "fix" the view...

or

- I start my app which will work fine
- I press the Home button exiting the app, my service though will (correctly) keep running
- when selecting my service from the notification-bar I will get once again :
  -Now my (fullscreen) app will have "moved" like 30-40 pixels downwards, creating an ugly black border or hole. When I move the scrollwheel it will move up and down, and when I press the Menu button (showing my ap''s menu) it will "fix" the view...

Any idea what the problem is ? The app is running on a ADP2 with Android 1.6
Thanks in advance !

Ok, after some testing I noticed that if I don't run the Activity on Fullscreen, but just leave the TtileBar away this won't happen...
Still this is no solution to me, I want it to be fullscreen...

Noticed siomething else, when I have the View with the black bar, and I press the home button it will "refresh" the View correctly just before actually going to the Home Screen :(